# How to update GUID in MS SQL via PHP/ODBC?

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, odbc, guid

I've been tasked with getting two MS SQL based products to synchronize. My predecessor was content to match records based on a combination of name and address, but both systems have a GUID, and only one is actually using it. So my thought was to match up my existing records and copy the GUID from one database to the other. But I can't seem to update a GUID in MS SQL using PHP and ODBC. The query fails silently. If I echo the query and copy/paste it into SQL Management Studio or Oracle SQL Developer, it works fine. The simplified version of my query looks like this:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE Contact SET SifGuid = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), '" . $this->GUID . "') ";
$SQL .= "WHERE contactID = " . $this->POSID . ";
```

Sending that query through odbc_exec fails. But like I mentioned, the same exact query works fine in SQL Management Studio or Oracle SQL Developer.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does Profiler show is actually being executed?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to PHP (my last job was doing desktop apps, so it's been awhile since I've done web stuff), so please pardon my ignorance, but how would I find out what Profiler is showing?

Answer (score 2):

When you query the data out of the first server, be sure you are converting the data to VARCHAR()

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(36),guidCol) AS guid FROM table
```

Then when you insert, you need to cast it back to a GUID value since it's already a string in PHP.

```
UPDATE table SET guidCol = CAST(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '" . $this->GUID . "')
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik, but no dice. Still won't work through odbc_exec, although odbc_error isn't showing anything wrong. But if I copy the query into SQL Developer, it executes just fine.